# Getting Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=255 during MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am running some map reduce task on huge dataset on four node cluster but getting exception with exit code - 255

```
16/08/04 08:07:19 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/08/04 08:07:27 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1470297644642_0001_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1470297644642_0001_01_000003
Exit code: 255
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=255: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:543)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:460)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:720)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 255
```

In log file - SLF4J:

> Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". SLF4J:
>   Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J: See
>   http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details. ��h��׶9�A@���P   VERSIONAPPLICATION_ACL MODIFY_APPVIEW_APP
>   APPLICATION_OWNEcentos(&container_1470297644642_0007_01_000007��stderr0stdout0syslog4142016-08-04
>   10:39:56,439 FATAL [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.YarnUncaughtExceptionHandler: Thread
>   Thread[main,5,main] threw an Error.  Shutting down now...
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JVMId.(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobID;ZJ)V
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:86)
>   2016-08-04 10:39:56,444 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil:
>   Exiting with status -1
>   (&container_1470297644642_0007_01_000013��stderr0stdout0syslog4142016-08-04
>   10:40:03,359 FATAL [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.YarnUncaughtExceptionHandler: Thread
>   Thread[main,5,main] threw an Error.  Shutting down now...

Comment: Could you check the container log? (You can use "yarn logs" command to retrieve the log)

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JVMId.<init>(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobID;ZJ)V
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:86)

Comment: Hi There, I am facing the exact same issue with my MapReduce application on EMR. Do you recall what you did to resolve the same? Any pointers would be highly appreciated.